# Browser autofill after page refresh on emptied input - is this a bug?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

An input field for a search is used. Then, the field is emptied to clear the search. But when the user refreshes the page, the field again has the search term in the input field. It appears to be due to auto-complete settings on a per-browser basis. Normally, the autocomplete is good to have, but emptying the field should overwrite that value, shouldn't it?

This appears to be a bug that should be submitted to Chrome and IE and Safari (Firefox doesn't seem to have this problem). But is it?

Or is there a way to properly clear that value when the input is cleared by the user? We don't want to disable autofill.

I tried $('myinput').prop('defaultValue','') in my search clear function and that did not work. That is, the property was changed, but when the page was refreshed, the previous value was again in the input field.

Comment: <  type=search autocomplete=off />

Comment: I don't see any reason why it shouldn't works (I tested locally). Maybe it's in your code. Can we have a bit of it ?

Comment: Well the question is how to get autofill not to override a user-emptied input of "" just on reload, since in other situations, autofill is wanted for this field.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes I notice this strange behavior on Chrome and Safari, when there are password fields in *the same form.* I guess, the browser looks for a password field to insert your saved credentials. Then it autofills (just guessing due to observation) the nearest textlike-input field, that appears prior the password field in DOM. As the browser is the last instance and you can not control it, *sometimes even autocomplete=off would not prevent to fill in credentials*. This readonly-fix worked for me.

```
 <!-- fix browser password fill in: 
     set readonly and set writeble on focus (click and tab) -->
 <input type="search" readonly  
     onfocus="$(this).removeAttr('readonly');"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can empty your textbox on page load event as follows.

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
 $('#myinput').prop('value','')
});
```

Comment: This might well be the answer, but it'd be great if you could explain how/why it fixes it in a few words too.

Comment: That basically wipes out autofill, which is not wanted. The question is why autofill won't clear even when the user clears the field (in some browsers), due to browser history filling the field.